# Find inherit css style value when all values below are strikethrough in computed?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, styles

I have the same page in two chrome tabs. This page has a configuration that if you change it, some styles are modified. 
The problem i have is that a particular style should not be changed but in fact it does. This is a `line-height` style.

The problem i'm having is that in one page the `line-height` is 14px and in the other is 18px and the same thing happens with `font-size`.

I search in the computed section of chrome developer tools but i can't found the source of that change because the `line-height` and `font-size` says `inherit` but all the values bellow are strikethrough. So my question is more in a general way to know where this values are been set?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 - Open Chrome Web Inspector.
 - Select the "Element" where you want to check the line height.
 - On the right hand side, you will find "styles".
 - Now scroll on the "styles" to find all the "line-height" styles from different styling files. 

You will see Inherited From section there.
Example:
```

[image]

Comment: The page is a local page so i can't give the url. 
Also, i have done that and i couldn't find the inherited base style.

Answer (score 0):

"Inherit" means the element gets its value for line-height from another (parent) element. I guess you modified such a parent element. You can avoid this by giving your element an exact value for line-height with !important.

```
.your-element{line-height: 14px!important;}
```

Comment: This is really not the answer i'm looking for because the styling of this is made by another team so the only thing i need is to find out where this `line-height` is inherited to tell the other team to change it